# Can't connect a button\label with variable\outlet in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I created 2 View Controllers: on the first I created a button when click on it you will open another View Controller with button and label. I already created outlet and variable for them.

**My question is:** when I'm trying to connect the button\label with variable\outlet I can't see selection around the button\label -> I mean that I can't connect them all. Why?

**P.S. DON'T PUT A MINUS I JUST NEW PROGRAMMER!**

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your IBOutlet declarations?
You have to declare UIButtons like this to make them work (connect) in Interface Builder :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
```

For a label its just the same :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;
```

I think you have either forgotten to write IBOutlet or your variable type is wrong.

Comment: It's quite common to have your outlets be `weak` since their superview will retain them.

Comment: Questions for clarification like "Can you post your IBOutlet declarations?" [should be left as comments instead of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I resolved the task.

I just needed to create a new `Objective-C class`, select that new class in **Identity Inspector** of the second **View Controller** and write all code in that new class.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this one too.

For anyone still confused, select the View Controller (the yellow box) in your Storyboard and then under Inspector select the [image] Identity Inspector.  See images.

Now you will be able to connect up the IBOutlet items in your interface .h file.

[image]

[image]